# Yarn crash [max number of completed apps kept in memory met]

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

During MapReduce processing of several jobs, Yarn did crash and the processing of jobs had stopped.
I successed to back the processing after killing jobs which were running (2jobs).
In the logs I find from the beginning of the crash :

`Max number of completed apps kept in state store met*: maxCompletedAppsInStateStore = 10000, removing app application_1500982512144_26754 from state store.
 2017-08-25 03:50:05,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager: *Application should be expired, max number of completed apps kept in memory met*: maxCompletedAppsInMemory = 10000, removing app application_1500982512144_26754 from memory`

After that , this message shows up several times in the log :

`Large response size 4742320 for call org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB.getApplications`

Have you any explication and solution of this issue ?